# Windbg Scripting Issue

Tags: windows, windbg

Debugging an application's use of msvcrt!_read. Found a nifty Windbg script online [Reversing on Windows: intercepting ReadFile](http://reversingonwindows.blogspot.com/2012/02/finding-appropriate-readfile.html) that I lightly edited:

```
$$ Windbg script to intercept when a file is being read.
bp msvcrt!_read
.while(1)
{
  g
  $$ Get parameters of _read()
  r $t0 = dwo(esp+4)
  r $t1 = dwo(esp+8)
  r $t2 = dwo(esp+0x0c)

  $$ Execute until return is reached
  pt

  $$ Read magic value in the buffer
  $$ CHANGE position in buffer here
  r $t5 = dwo(@$t1+0x00)
  r
  .printf "hFile=%p buffer=%p count=%p\n", @$t0, @$t1, @$t2

  $$ Check if magic value matches
  $$ CHANGE constant here
  db @$t1 $$ had to put this here b/c .if never executed 'clause'
  .if(@$t5 == 0x00000000) $$magic string
  {
    db @$t1

    $$ UNCOMMENT below to break in the debugger
    .break
  }
}

$$ Clear BP for ReadFile (assume it is the 0th one)
bc 0
```

I tried using the following 'magic string' of bytes:

```
77 30 30 66
```

in:

```
.if(@$t5 == 0x77303066) $$magic string
```

However, it never meets that condition. Most frustrating part is that I see the magic string when the script runs the 'db@$t1'

```
eax=00000400 ebx=02895cc4 ecx=75b7c2d6 edx=771f70f4 esi=017d0ab8 edi=028b2534
eip=75b7c2d6 esp=03d2fbec ebp=00000003 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
msvcrt!_read+0xd1:
75b7c2d6 c3              ret
hFile=00000003 lpBuffer=05f30020 nNumberOfBytesToRead=00000400
05f30020  77 30 30 66 00 00 00 2e-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  w00f............
05f30030  00 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 00 00-00 2e 00 00 00 2e 2e 00  ................
05f30040  00 2e 2e 00 00 00 04 00-00 00 2e 2e 00 00 2e 2e  ................
05f30050  00 00 2e 2e 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 01 2e  ................
05f30060  00 2e 00 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e-00 00 00 2e 00 00 00 2e  ................
```

I've also tried changing the magic string in the wds script to little endian, still doesnt work though.

How may I format the if statement to trigger in the above script using the magic string 'w00f?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first four bytes of the file (`77` `30` `30` `66`) will be read into `@$t5` in little-endian format.

So `.if(@$t5 == 0x77303066)` should be `.if(@$t5 == 0x66303077)`.

Comment: And if this doesn't work, `.printf` the value of `@$t5` to troubleshoot further.

Comment: it works.  could have sworn i already tried that lol. Thanks Jason